# Use multiple edit text and perform calculation

Tags: android

I am trying to take multiple input using edit text and i want to perform calculation .I am trying to develop a freight calculator in this one field type of delivery normal or express and other field is weight of package. i have no idea how to take input from both and calculate price.

Comment: You should add some more info about what your issue is and what you already have done. Add some code snippets of what you've tried. Also, I suggest reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to both `EditText` fields at the class level, for example:

```
private EditText firstEditText;
private EditText secondEditText;
```

Within the the `onCreate()` function in your Activity, or the `onCreateView()` within your Fragment, bind the reference to your view:

**Activity**

```
firstEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_first);
secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_second);
```

**Fragment**

```
firstEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_first);
secondEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_second);
```

Then on some click event or at whatever point you'll want to pull the value from both of the `EditText`'s:

```
String firstValue = firstEditText.getText().toString();
String secondValue = secondEditText.getText().toString();
```

Now you're free to parse/calculate/interrogate the values however you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it.

To collect input from user use EditText, 
sample shown below replicate this with different **ID** for edit text.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your quantity here"/>

    <EditText

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="input space for user"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>
```

use TextView to display answer

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

Create a button that user can press when he fills up the inputs required

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:onClick="simulate"/>
```

now in your JAVA file make an onClick event handler

```
public void simulate(View view) {
    EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    EditText edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);

    l1 = Integer.valueOf(edit1.getText().toString());
    l2 = Integer.valueOf(edit2.getText().toString());

    //perform your calculation here

    TextView rs1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        rs1.setText(""+ your answer);
}
```